# jQuery .error event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is such a lame question to ask, but it seems like I'm having trouble getting my brain back in gear after the Christmas period.

Simple question, I'm using the jQuery .error event to replace broken images using this bit of script

```
    $('#slideshowContainer img[name=imgStockItem]').error(function(){
         $(this).attr('src', '/assets/images/no-image-large.png');
    });
```

What I really want to do is have something like an if/else deal, where if the image is broken do this, else, do this.

I tried this:

```
   if($('#slideshowContainer img[name=imgStockItem]').error()){
          alert("true");
   } else {
          alert("false");
   }
```

But that just returns a true everytime, broken image or not.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.error()` event means.. error.

To know if image was loaded successfully, handle the `.load` event.

Now comes the tricky part.. to have jQuery (or JavaScript in general) trigger any of those events, you'll have to manually assign the image `src` otherwise it will be "too late".

So, have such image tag:

```
<img name="imgStockItem" my_src="image_source_here.png" />
```

Then such code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideshowContainer img[name=imgStockItem]').each(function(index) {
        $(this).error(function() {
            $(this).attr('src', '/assets/images/no-image-large.png');
            $("#StatusDiv").append("image #" + (index + 1) + " is broken<br />");
         });

        $(this).load(function() {
            $("#StatusDiv").append("image #" + (index + 1) + " loaded successfully<br />");
        });

        $(this).prop("src", $(this).attr("my_src"));
    });
});
```

`StatusDiv` is just example for container showing the status of each image.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/w5MrS/1/).

Comment: True, just fiddled it and neither event triggers. Going to delete this, as there is already better answer.

Comment: @user1001421 OK found why it didn't work and changed everything, see my edit please.

Comment: Looks just the job. Strange the way that things that should be so simple turn out to be pretty hard. Big thanks dude.

Comment: @user1001421 Cheers just had to figure out the "too late" part. :/

Answer (score 1):

Im going to make an assumption here but i think this maybe your problem

> The event handler must be attached before the browser fires the error event, which is why the example sets the src attribute after attaching the handler.

See http://api.jquery.com/error/

You will have to attach the event when the `src` is set as once the browser renders the element it will make the request to the defined source, your problem is that it has thrown the error and you haven't caught it because the handler wasn't applied at that point.

You could try this (place before all your image markup):

```
$('#slideshowContainer').on({
    error: function() {
        $(this).attr('src', '/assets/images/no-image-large.png');
    }, 
    load: function() {
        // loaded successfully
    }
}, 'img[name=imgStockItem]');
```

Comment: @user1001421 no problem, im not sure your selected answer will work for you - atleast not for error's

Comment: Actually I think I spoke too soon. I think the selected answer won't work after all. But at least I know where I was going wrong.

Comment: @user1001421 Does my solution prove to be of any use?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm not sure if the problem is due to #slideshowContainer img[name=imgStockItem] can hold up to 9 images, and I really should only be testing the first one. IE: $('#slideshowContainer img[name=imgStockItem]:first').error(

Comment: I think I might be approaching this from the wrong angle. All I want to do is check if the image is broken, in which case replace it with another. If not broken then do a load of other stuff, start up a slide show etc. Can I try pre-loading the image before actually loading it. Just to test if it's there or not?

Comment: Yes, kind of preloading.. see my new answer.